# Give an algorithm to find number of line segments that contain $4$ or more houses, if we are given $x$- and $y$-coordinates of all houses in the town.

Tags: algorithms

> Give an algorithm to find number of line segments that contain $4$ or more houses, if we are given $x$- and $y$-coordinates of all houses in the town.

In C I have an incomplete program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main()
{
    clrscr();
    int arr[10][2],x1,y1,x2,y2;
    float m;
    arr={(0,0),(1,0),(1,2),(1,1),(2,5),(4,3),(4,5),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4)};
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
    x1=arr[i][0];
    y1=arr[i][1];
    for(int j=0;j<10;j++)
    {
         if(i!=j)
         {
        x2=arr[j][0];
        y2=arr[j][1];
        m=(y2-y1)/(x2-x1);
```

Comment: Your program is illegible without line breaks.  It takes two spaces and a return to make a displayed line break on the site.  Did you look at your post after you posted it?  Then this is a math site, not a programming site.  Posting a code snippet without explanation of how it is supposed to work makes it very hard on people to answer.  -1 and vote to close as off topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
double lines[45][2];
int x1, y1, x2, y2;
double m, b;
int index=0;
for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
x1=arr[i][0];
y1=arr[i][1];
for (int j=i+1; j<=10; j++) {
x2=arr[j][0];
y2=arr[j][1];
m=(y2-y1)/(x2-x1);
b=y2-m*x2;
lines[index][0]=m;
lines[index][1]=b;
index++;
}
}

double unique_lines[45][2];
int nunique=1;
unique_lines[0][0]=lines[0][0];
unique_lines[0][1]=lines[0][1];
for (int k=1; k<45; k++) {
int isunique=1;
int m=lines[k][0];
int b=lines[k][1];
for (int l=0; l<nunique; l++) {
if (unique_lines[l][0]==m && unique_lines[l][1]==b) {
isunique=0;
break;
}
if (isunique==1) {
unique_lines[nunique][0]=m;
unique_lines[nunique][1]=b;
nunique++;
}
}
}

int count=0;
for (int k=0; k<nunique; k++) {
int num=0;
m=unique_lines[k][0];
b=unique_lines[k][1];
for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
x=arr[i][0];
y=arr[i][1];
if (y==m*x+b) {
num++;
}
}
if (num>=4) {
count++;
}
}
```